# How can I pass a form-selection value to QnA maker?

Tags: botframework, azure-language-understanding, azure-qna-maker, formflow

I'm trying to build a set of pre-configured questions (with the help of form filler) whose answers can be fetched from QnA maker. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you explain how this question is different from your other one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53874128/a-troubleshooting-bot

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A troubleshooting bot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53874128/a-troubleshooting-bot)

Comment: @KyleDelaney, My other question was categorized as too broad while I asked if QnA maker and Form flow can talk to each other. It was now closed so I thought of asking the 2nd question without explaining the scenario.

Comment: Based on what you've said so far, it still seems like neither FormFlow nor QnAMaker suit your needs. I think you want a sort of branching waterfall dialog. Please have a look at the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-manage-conversation-flow?view=azure-bot-service-3.0) to get an idea of how to build a dialog. If you still think FormFlow and QnAMaker are what you need then please explain exactly what you're trying to do and why. We'd like to help you but we need you to work with us. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Are you still working on this?

Comment: Yes. Based on the answer on other question, I tried to create dynamic enum after reading SharePoint list which didn't work and gave me casting message. I'm going through branching waterfall dialog and will you posted.

Comment: All right, do you want to close this question and ask a new one when you're ready?